# I get an error that says that the beginning is not defined. how do I fix it?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a hangman game.

Python keeps telling me that `get_word` is not defined, but I'm not sure really as to why it says that.

```
get_word():
    dictionary = ["number","one","hyper","active","knuckle","head","ninja"]
    import random

process_guess():
    while keep_playing:
        dictionary=["number","one","hyper","active","knuckle","head","ninja"]
        word=choice(dictionary)
        word_len=len(word)
        guesses=word_len * ['_']
        max_incorrect=7
        alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
        letters_tried=""
        number_guesses=0
        letters_correct=0
        incorrect_guesses=0
        print_game_rules(max_incorrect,word_len)
        while (incorrect_guesses != max_incorrect) and (letters_correct != word_len):
            clues()
            letter=get_letter()
            if len(letter)==1 and letter.isalpha():
                if letters_tried.find(letter) != -1:
                    print ("letter has already been used", letter)
                else:
                    letters_tried = letters_tried + letter
                    first_index=word.find(letter)
                    if  first_index == -1:
                        incorrect_guesses= incorrect_guesses +1
                        print ("The",letter,"is not the unknown word.")
                    else:
                        print("The",letter,"is in the unknown word.")
                        letters_correct=letters_correct+1
                        for i in range(word_len):
                            if letter == word[i]:
                                guesses[i] = letter
            else:
                print ("Please guess a single letter in the alphabet.")
                print("victory:",no guesses ')


play():
    1 = yes
    0 = no
    print(("play again? (1-yes, 0-no")):

print("get the current guess letter:", current)





main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, new functions are defined using the `def` keyword. So do:

```
def get_word():
```

and everywhere else you want to define a function.

Comment: So, you changed the code in your question to add that. Was that not your question then?

Comment: no yes, that was part of it. I just wasn't sure as to why it kept saying that. But it was more of whether or not the code as a whole would not run.

Comment: Well, there's quite a few potential reasons why that code might not run. (1) `main()` is not defined; (2) `1 = yes` makes no sense; (3) the indenting appears all messed up; (4) `choice` (presumably from `random`?) is unqualified; (5) `no _'s guesses'` is a syntax error. So I would try to clear those up first.